# How can I create Launch Screen storyboard with different content for different targets?

Tags: ios, storyboard, launch, launchimage, launch-screen

How can I create Launch Screen storyboard with different content for different targets? Is it possible to add some logic to the Launch Screen storyboard?

Comment: AFAIK, how can you add logic to the Launch Screen storyboard as it has no corresponding ViewController?

Comment: So, launch screen storyboard can be used only for autoresizing. Will you add your comment as the answer?

Comment: Maybe this could be done as part of the build process? So wasteful to duplicate the storyboard per target just to change a color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's impossible because storyboard has no corresponding ViewController. Launch screen storyboard can be used only for autoresizing.